# We have $a_{n}=n^{x^{2}-5}$ and $A$={$x\in \mathbb{R} : \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges}. What is the value of $ \ supA $?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

So i have the following question:
$a_{n}=n^{x^{2}-5}$ and $A$={$x\in \mathbb{R} : \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges}. What is the value of $ \ supA $?

Using the p-series test i solved it as $x^{2}-5>1$ and therefore $x>\sqrt{6}$. Which means that $A$ is the set $A$={$x\in\mathbb{R}: x>\sqrt{6}$} therefore the Supremum would be $+\infty$ and the Infimum $\sqrt{6}$.
The answer in the book is not like this and it would be really helpful for me to undrstand what is wrong with my logic.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Annalisa

Comment: If you want the series converges, then you have the constraint $x^2-5<-1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{x^2-5} < +\infty \Longleftrightarrow x^2-5 <-1$$

So $A=(-2,2)$, so $\sup(A)=2$.